# Automated way to find number of usages?

Tags: java

Are there any open source tools that automate the functionality of finding the number of usages of a Java API?  I can figure out this information for one class at a time in my IDE.  I want to use this information to create a rudimentary report on the speed of adoption of a particular library.  I would create a daily report on the number of usages of dozens of classes, and I would report on several code bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try **Macker**. Its style is to report references to configured classes as errors, but that's fine.  It can be run from an automated build.  Thanks Robert.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Macker sounds interesting to me, too because of its "preemptive" approach similar to e.g. Checkstyle. When we used Dependency Finder on the project I mentioned it was quite late. We had an existing JEE system with already too many dependencies. It was on the way to becoming a maintenance nightmare. The tool basically helped us in developing an approach and finding a good starting point for refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with one of [those tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-analyzers) for analyzing dependencies in Java code. Let it work on your source tree, a package or a single class and see if you can export the results to XML or something like that. I've used [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) in a project about two years ago and I think it should do what you want. Not sure about the export to XML, though.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can right click on a method name or class and go to the References menu and from there you can choose the scope of where you want to search for classes that reference that item.

Is that what you need?